# Is there a legitimate reason to use an encoded word in any header other than the subject?

Tags: email, encoding, charset, smtp-headers

Encoded words allow non-US-ASCII characters to be encoded as US-ASCII and thus placed into email headers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word

Encoded words are often used in the Subject header, especially when the Subject is in another language, such as Spanish:

```
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?=A1Hola,_se=F1or!?=
```

Question:  Is there a legitimate reason to use an encoded word in any header other than the Subject?

**Answer:**

Examples from RFC 2047

- **Display Names in email addresses**: To: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Keld_J=F8rn_Simonsen?=
- **Comments**: From: Nathaniel Borenstein  (=?iso-8859-8?b?7eXs+SDv4SDp7Oj08A==?=)

**Edit:**

I actually received one of these recently.  The "guilty" party was Airmail.  Here's the headers (with the email address changed):

```
To: "=?utf-8?Q?john=40doe.org?=" <john@doe.org>
Message-ID: <etPan.534b7be1.6c8b4667.233@myMac.local>
Subject: check this out
X-Mailer: Airmail (237)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Human names aren't limited to US-ASCII so anything involving a person's name (e.g. `To:`, `From:'`, `Reply-to:` and `CC:`) are  legitimate. [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) shows examples of this. It wouldn't surprise me if product name headers (`X-Mailer:`) showed up with encoded characters as well.

Comment: Not the local part or the domain, but the display name.  Gotcha.